# How to open a new window in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a new window in button click.I have used a code.

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.open('YOURPAGE.aspx','_blank');</script>")
```

It is behaving like a pop up window,but it is not working in IE 7.0 & Chrome.Please help me to solve that issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most modern browsers, the browser will prevent the pop-up if the javascript wasn't run as the result of a user action.  Actions like onClick are ok, but script that executes as soon as the page loads will usually be blocked.

HTH,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the target to _blank on an anchor tag instead of a button? e.g.

```
<a href="yourpage.aspx" target="_blank" />
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I have tried this.but requirement is when user click the ASp.net button then i have to open a new tab.

Comment: @PrateekSaluja: Are there any other requirements (such as recording the click)?  If not, then I would not have the button cause a postback, and just run the javascript when the button is clicked.  That will not only prevent the popup from being blocked, but it will also save a round trip to the server.

Comment: Thanks but we have to open a new tab into button click

Comment: @Prateek: This is actually Brian.  On the asp.net button, you do do something like <asp:Button runat="server" onClientClick="myFunction()"/> and that will call a javascript function named myFunction.  I thought there was a property you could set to prevent postbacks, but I'm not seeing it right now.  At the very least, you could have your function return false.  I know that will work.

Comment: Why a button click? What reason is a button a fixed requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the prevalence of very irritating adverts and attacks based around opening a popup window as soon as a page loads, most modern browsers will block them.

You can only have a popup if it is direct response to a user event (e.g. in an onclick handler).

You cannot trigger on at page load time.